# $\sqrt{2}$ as the limit of a decreasing sequence of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sqrt{2}$ is the limit of the sequence $\{1, 1.4, 1.41, 1.414, ...\}$. How are we to express it as the limit of a decreasing sequence of rational numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply round up at each decimal point.
We know $\sqrt{2} \approx 1.41421356$.
Hence define the sequence by $\{2, 1.5, 1.42, 1.415, 1.4143, 1.41422, 1.414214,\cdots\}$.